# Databricks - String manipulation via sql command

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table column that I need to get from databricks whatever appears between the 15th and 16th appearance of the character # as follows the following example:

Column
1234##E#A#1234#01/01/4500#X#*ABCDE#7#1##N#N#N#0#Z.POIUS.LKJS_20200103#0#

Results
Z.POIUS.LKJS_20200103

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`select  reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index('1234##E#A#1234#01/01/4500#X#*ABCDE#7#1##N#N#N#0#Z.POIUS.LKJS_20200103#0#', '#', 16)),'#', 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the string and get the 15th element, eg something like this:

```
%sql
SELECT *, 
  regexp_extract( yourCol, '(?:[^#]*(#)){15}(.[^#]+)', 2 ) xregex,
  split( yourCol, '#' )[15] AS  xsplit    
FROM tmp
```

I was experimenting with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/4ftpqi/1/) which may be appropriate for some cases too.  My results:

[image]